# Color scheme not affecting whitespace in Vim

Tags: terminal, vim

I have been trying to add a color scheme to my `.vimrc`, but for whatever reason it's not wanting to highlight the whitespace to the right of my lines. Here's what my `.vimrc` looks like right now under the color scheme:

[image: .vimrc]

What command should I use to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Syntax elements only match on actual text, all the empty "background" is highlighted via the [`:help hl-Normal`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#hl-Normal) default group named `Normal`.

It looks like your colorscheme defines separate `ctermbg=` attributes for the various highlight groups instead of setting the background once and for all on the `Normal` group. Sometimes, this can be a result of a wrong detection of [`:help 'background'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27background%27); you could try forcing it by putting

```
set background=dark
```

before your `:colorscheme` command.

Also, not all colorschemes support all output variants; some are GUI-only or terminal-only, or assume a certain number of available colors.

Comment: Tried putting the background before the colorscheme, no luck on that end. I'm using the bash terminal for ubuntu on Windows, would that make any difference?

Comment: Trying something different (like PuTTY) may be promising, also, what about other colorschemes? Do they all have that problem? Also, please add your actual colorscheme (name or link) to the question; maybe someone already has had similar experiences with it.